# Facebook post to page issue about title and description

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to facebook page. Everything works apart from "Title" and "Description".

I use the following code to post.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM social_settings WHERE id = 1";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
     'app_id' => $row['facebook_app_id'],
     'app_secret' => $row['facebook_app_secret'],
     'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    $linkData = [
        'link' => 'http://www.example.com/property/detail/'.$property_id,
        'message' => $title,
        "source" => 'http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg'
    ];

    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, $row['facebook_token']);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

I also use the following OG data ;

```
    <meta property="og:type"            content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title"           content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:site_name"       content="Example">
    <meta property="og:url"             content="http://www.example.com/property/detail/<?php echo $property_id; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image"           content="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $image; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image:type"      content="image/jpg" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id"          content="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <meta property="og:description"     content="<?php echo $desc; ?>" />
```

When I checked the cource code, everything is echoed out properly.

Now the problem is, when i checke the facebook page, Link, Message and source are posted but underneath the image, it is also displayed "Title" and "Description"

See image;

[image: Screen shot of facebook page post]

How can change the TITLE and DESCRIPTION?

Comment: Check your OG meta data using the Facebook debug tool.

Comment: I have just checked via facebook degub and also http://opengraphcheck.com. everything seems fine

Comment: Actual example URL for us to check?

Comment: I found the problem. The page was redirecting to "coming soon" folder as the site was off. And the og tags were set to default there. But now, I also need to find a solution for another issue. I am posting the article from admin of the website and i am not sure Facebook SDK will be able to access the admin page as it needs logging in.

Comment: What matters is whether `http://www.example.com/property/detail/...` is accessible without login, not any admin page.

Comment: Aah so no matter where I post the article as long as facebook can access it without logging in. Great. Let me see if i can get it working

Comment: Now the issue is still there for some reason. I removed the og tags from coming soon page and i also made the site online. but when i post the article from admin the TITLE and DESCRIPTION is not displayed as it should. When I debug the url on Facebook, it collects the correct data but I needed to click the SCRAPE AGAIN button to do that otherwise debug result was also displaying the old og tag details

Comment: Well if you served wrong OG meta data before, then you will have to clear the cache for the affected URLs, unless you want to wait until they get crawled again.

Comment: Where can i clear the cache? do i need to do that everytime i post something?

Comment: _"Where can i clear the cache?"_ - google it. _"do i need to do that everytime i post something?"_ - something new, you mean? Depends, are you outputting the correct meta tags to begin with now?

Comment: As far as the Facebook debug is concerned, meta tags are correct. It displays the correct data. I will search for clearing the cache. Thanks for all the help you have provided so far.

Comment: Upon trying more and testing, i finally realise that Facebook is posting the first og data for the article. When try posting new articles, everything works perfectly so above code works just fine. Thanks for all the help